# Delphi / Indy resolve DNS domain by host name lookup

Tags: delphi, dns, indy10

I'm trying to use a hardcoded AName, some code using JNI on Delphi 10.1 update 2, and TIdDNSResolver to do the following:

1) Get the device DNS server(s) from the device interface config (works!)

2) Do a lookup on the DNS server to retrieve that server's domain name (fails!)

3) Append the DNS Domain to the hardcoded AName (not there yet)

4) Use the FQDN AName to lookup the server IP Address (not there yet)

So far using JNI functions in Delphi I can get the DNS server(s) IP Address. When I  try to lookup the domain name I'm failing. Here's my code:

```
dns.Host := s;
dns.WaitingTime := 2048;
dns.QueryType := [qtDName];
dns.Resolve('hard_coded_server_name');
for i := 0 to Pred(dns.QueryResult.Count) do
begin
  r := dns.QueryResult[i];
  case r.RecType of
    qtDName:  begin
                txt := TTextRecord(r);
                Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(txt.Text);
              end;
  end;
end;
```

I'm certain that I'm using the TResultRecord incorrectly, but couldn't find docs on how to do this correctly. Could someone (Remy?) please explain how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdDNSResolver` does not use `TTextRecord` for `qtDName` response records. `TTextRecord` is only used for `qtTXT` and `qtHINFO` records (`THINFORecord` derives from `TTextRecord`).

Looking at the source code for `TIdDNSResolver`, I see that `DNAME` is actually an *unhandled* response type (I do not know why), so `TIdDNSResolver` will end up using the `TResultRecord` class as-is for `DNAME` records.  And because of that, `DNAME` record data will not be parsed at all, and `r.RecType` will not be `qtDName` like you are expecting (technically, it will actually be unassigned and default to 0, which happens to be `qtA`).  However, the raw answer data will be in `r.RData`, at least.

Note that a `DNAME` lookup may result in `CNAME` response records (amongst others).  `CNAME` records are represented in `QueryResult` as `TNAMERecord` objects, where `r.RecType` will be `qtName`.

I have [checked in a fix](http://indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changelog/20161116.aspx) (SVN rev 5377):

- added a new `TDNAMERecord` class for parsing `DNAME` data.
- made sure the `TResultRecord.RecType` property is assigned a value for known record types (even if they are not parsed).
- added a new `TResultRecord.TypeCode` property for unknown record types that cannot be expressed in the `TResultRecord.RecType` property.

For example:

```
dns.Host := s;
dns.WaitingTime := 2048;
dns.QueryType := [qtDName];
dns.Resolve('hard_coded_server_name');
for i := 0 to Pred(dns.QueryResult.Count) do
begin
  r := dns.QueryResult[i];
  case r.RecType of
    qtName: begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('CNAME: ' + TNAMERecord(r).HostName);
    end;
    qtDName: begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('DNAME: ' + TDNAMERecord(r).HostName);
    end;
    // other types as needed ...
  else
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(r.TypeCode) + ': ' + ToHex(r.RData));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: you rock. :-)
\m/

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Just to make sure I understand, this new TDNAMERecord provides a field that provides the DNS Domain name? Or do I need to parse the .HostName?

Comment: @DeCoder the `HostName` *is* the domain name.

Comment: One thing that I noticed with revision 5377 that doesn't seem to jive with your code example is that the qtCName value hasn't been defined in the TQueryRecordTypes enumerated type, even though the TCNAMERecord has been defined. Is this an oversight? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DeCoder: That was a typo on my part, it should have been `qtName` instead of `qtCName`. I have corrected the example. There is no `TCNAMERecord` class, there is `TNAMERecord` instead, which is what `qtName` uses.

Comment: This is not working... in the sense of what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm sending a resolve request with the AName of the host sans domain, in the hopes of looking up the domain. This ALWAYS fails. If I send the resolve request with the FQDN appended to the AName, I get back an SOA record. In converting the result to HEX I get a large meaningless number. If I convert the HEX string to string, it's partially readable and not what I'm looking for. Is there a flag that can tell the DNS server to search all domains for the host, returning any domains that contain that host name?

Comment: @DeCoder: fails *HOW* exactly? You need to be more specific. Have you read [RFC 6672](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6672) yet? It explains how a `DNAME` lookup works and what types of records it returns. What types of records is the DNS server actually returning to you? You can use the new `r.TypeCode` property if `r.RecType` does not tell you (or use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to analyze the DNS response). As for SOA, `r.RecType` will be `qtSOA` and `r` will point at a `TSOARecord` object, which has many properties, some of which are strings.

Comment: "DNS Server Reports Query Server Error" is the result of querying without the FQDN appendage. As for RFC 6672, that leads me to believe that using a DNAME lookup might not be the way to go, since what I'm looking to accomplish is to send a known A Name in the situation where I don't know the FQDN that the A Name exists in, but I need to find it. Is there a more appropriate way to accomplish this?

Comment: What makes you think DNS is the right way to resolve a hostname to a FQDN in the first place? Something like that would probably be better handled using `getaddrinfo()` to resolve the hostname to its IP address(es), and then use `getnameinfo()` to resolve the IP address(es) to FQDN(s).  Let the OS decide if/how to use DNS for any lookups, if it needs to do so.

Comment: Can't use that on IOS and Android though, right? I looked at those, but discarded them because they are platform specific calls, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128395/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-decoder).